# CLR thread blocks on exception

Tags: c#-4.0, clr, windbg

I am trying to debug a very weird problem.  My C# application deadlocks and I am using WinDbg to figure out what's going on.

It seems that one thread is blocked inside exception:

```
0:042> !mk  
Thread 42:
    SP       IP
00:U 0abeda7c 76eb015d ntdll!NtWaitForMultipleObjects+0x15  
01:U 0abeda84 754f15e9 KERNELBASE!WaitForMultipleObjectsEx+0x100  
02:U 0abedb20 750e19fc kernel32!WaitForMultipleObjectsExImplementation+0xe0  
03:U 0abedb68 750e41d8 kernel32!WaitForMultipleObjects+0x18  
04:U 0abedb84 75108074 kernel32!WerpReportFaultInternal+0x186  
05:U 0abedbf0 75107f33 kernel32!WerpReportFault+0x70  
06:U 0abedc04 75107828 kernel32!BasepReportFault+0x20  
07:U 0abedc14 751077a7 kernel32!UnhandledExceptionFilter+0x1af  
08:U 0abedca0 76f074ff ntdll!__RtlUserThreadStart+0x62  
09:U 0abedca8 76f073dc ntdll!_EH4_CallFilterFunc+0x12  
0a:U 0abedcbc 76f07281 ntdll!_except_handler4+0x8e  
0b:U 0abedce4 76eeb499 ntdll!ExecuteHandler2+0x26  
0c:U 0abedd08 76eeb46b ntdll!ExecuteHandler+0x24  
0d:U 0abedd2c 76eeb40e ntdll!RtlDispatchException+0x127  
0e:U 0abeddb8 76ea0133 ntdll!KiUserExceptionDispatcher+0xf  
0f:M 0abee104 0654c0bb MyApp.Raster`1[[System.UInt64,mscorlib]].RemoveSubset(System.Nullable`1<UInt64>, System.Nullable`1<UInt64>)(+0x5b IL,+0x103 Native)
```

...

I am not sure why the thread blocks instead of just throwing exception.
I loaded SOS.dll and SOSex.dll and used !PrintException command:

```
Exception object: 3f8c328c  
Exception type:   System.NullReferenceException  
Message:          Object reference not set to an instance of an object.  
InnerException:   <none>  
StackTrace (generated):  
SP       IP       Function  
0ABEE104 0654C0BB UNKNOWN!MyApp.Raster`1[[System.UInt64, mscorlib]].RemoveSubset(System.Nullable`1<UInt64>, System.Nullable`1<UInt64>)+0x103
```

Have you ever experienced anything like this?  What could be the cause?

Thank you.

Comment: showing code and where things go wrong is probably gonna help you get meaningful responses.

Answer (score 2):

It is trying to **terminate** your app, display the Windows Error Reporting crash dialog.  Hard to guess why you don't see it.  With of course non-zero odds that your customer saw it, created a minidump and sent it to you to figure out what caused it.  Well, your MyApp.Raster.RemoveSubset() method did.

Just don't *ever* let it get this far.  By the time the WER dialog gets displayed, you've lost a lot of valuable information about the exception.  Like the exception message and the Holy Stack trace.  Simply write an event handler for the AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException event and log or display the value of e.UnhandledException.ToString().  And terminate the app yourself before the Windows has to do it, Environment.Exit().

Comment: Hans, according to [my research](http://debugging.wellisolutions.de/wer-influence-attaching/), the information is not gone yet. You can even create the [LocalDumps Registry key while the dialog is displayed](http://debugging.wellisolutions.de/wer-activate-localdumps-shortterm/).

Comment: Not exactly the point of the answer.  The point was not have to look at it.  And avoid putting the customer in a situation where he can never discover a simple workaround by himself.

Comment: I have an exception handler higher in the stack that should catch any exceptions.  Unfortunately, I am not allowed to share code.  

I will add event handler to AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException and see what happens.